# recibir parametros poniendolos directo como props y solo mostrarlos en el template con vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuex

Tengo una tabla en vue que permite mostrar la siguiente información de una venta o carrito abandonado:

```
<div class="row col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
                  <table class="table col-sm-4">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Subtotal</th>
                          <td class="table-light">{{ subtotal | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Descuento</th>
                          <td class="table-light">{{ discount | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Envío</th>
                          <td class="table-light">{{ shipping | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Impuesto</th>
                          <td class="table-light">{{ taxes | currency }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <th>TOTAL</th>
                          <th class="total">{{ total | currency }}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El componente debe recibir los siguientes parametros
subtotal
shipping
taxes
discount
total

y tengo que contemplar que el envío no siempre estará presente, y cuando esto ocurra no mostrar la información de envio.

Deberia recibir esos parametros poniendolos directo como props y solo mostrarlos en el template? Como realizarlo correctamente?

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné de la siguiente manera:

```
<template>
  <styleGuideSection-view title="Tabla de resumen de venta">
    <b-container fluid>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <w-purchase-summary-table 
            subtotal="100"
            discount="20"
            shipping="20"
            taxes="21"
            total="101">
          </w-purchase-summary-table>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
      <b-row>
        <b-col>
          <p class="bigger bold">Implementación</p>
          <code>
            <pre>
              &lt;w-purchase-summary-table 
                &nbsp;subtotal="100" 
                &nbsp;discount="20" 
                &nbsp;taxes="21" 
                &nbsp;total="101"&gt;
              &lt;/w-purchase-summary-table&gt;
            </pre>
          </code>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>
    </b-container>
  </styleGuideSection-view>
</template>

  <script>
import styleGuideSection from '@/components/styleguide/StyleGuideSection'
import purchaseSummaryTable from '@/components/layout/templates/purchaseSummaryTable/PurchaseSummaryTable'
 export default {
  name: 'table-guide',
  components: {
    'styleGuideSection-view': styleGuideSection,
    'w-purchase-summary-table': purchaseSummaryTable
  },
```

y en la implementacion tambien con :

```
<template>
  <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-center">
  <div class="row col-lg-6 d-flex justify-content-center">
    <table class="table col-sm-4">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Subtotal</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ subtotal | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Descuento</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ discount | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Envío</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ shipping | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Impuesto</th>
          <td class="table-light">{{ taxes | currency }}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>TOTAL</th>
          <th class="total">{{ total | currency }}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

 <script>
export default {
  name: 'w-purchase-summary-table',
  props: {
    subtotal: Number,
    discount: Number,
    shipping: Number,
    taxes: Number,
    total: Number
  }
}
</script>
```